# Possible to disable firefox and chrome default caching?

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm having a problem with firefox caching, when i change a site redirection firefox decides that it needs to cache this.

The point is I wan't to create a test that tests editing a redirection works, but this caching prevents me from doing this.

Is there a way to disable firefox caching? or better yet delete it when needed?

NOTE: It's not cookies but the actual firefox cache.

I'm using webdriver C# version.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this page:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40

To disable Firefox caching you can try:
Create a new profile with `firefox.exe -ProfileManager`

Go to the Firefox profile directory and add the following to prefs.js:

```
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);
user_pref("network.http.use-cache", false);
```

Tell Selenium to use the custom Firefox profile (This is Java):

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("Selenium");
FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot as I was having the same issues with Ruby and Watir so I adapted this solution for my use case, in the following way: 1) No need to create a custom firefox profile and to make changes to "pref.js", 2) Set the cache preferences for the current profile directly in the ruby script with, for example: `profile["browser.cache.disk.enable"] = false `. This is only one of the four cache settings, but the syntax is of course the same for all of them.

Answer (score 4):

To disable chrome caching:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

List of available command-line arguments you can see [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-application-cache).

Comment: I believe this has been deprecated. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447206

Comment: so what is the answer now?