# How to clear history in Rselenium's internal web browser?

Tags: r, rselenium

In web browsers it is possible to clear history.

How is it possible to clear history in `firefox` browser in `RSelenium` using R commands?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461472/how-to-clear-browser-cache-automatically-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Rishabh thank you. I ckecked this but this is for the general selenium and I didn't find anything in documentation of R selenium

Comment: please check whether there is a  possibility to run the browser in a custom profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Possible to disable firefox and chrome default caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009823/possible-to-disable-firefox-and-chrome-default-caching)

In `RSelenium` and firefox you could pass as follows:

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(
  list(
    "browser.cache.disk.enable" = FALSE,
    "browser.cache.memory.enable" = FALSE,
    "browser.cache.offline.enable" = FALSE,
    "network.http.use-cache" = FALSE
  )
)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```

Comment: If I try to run the function fprof I receive this error `Error: unexpected '=' in:
"        browser.cache.offline.enable = FALSE,
        network.http.use-cache ="` is there anything additional I should bare in mind?

Comment: @foc good spot those names should be quoted. Have updated answer.

Comment: In the `makeFirefoxProfile` help document it notes: "Windows doesn't come with command-line zip capability. Installing rtools
https://CRAN.R-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html is a 
straightforward way to gain this capability.". This maybe the issue.